# Unable to call web service 2nd time From jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, json, telerik

I am unable to call web service 2nd time from jQuery function code is here.

Page:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCityByPinCode() {
        var path = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoComplete"].ToString() %>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "" + path + "/CityBasedOnPinCode",
            data: "{pincode: '" + $("#<%=ntxbPostCode.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(data, status) {
        var city = document.getElementById('<%= tbxCity.ClientID %>');
        var val1 = data.d;
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_CompanyDetails1_tbxCity").value = val1;
    }

    function OnError(request, status, error) {
        alert(request.statusText);
    }
</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
<body>
 <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="ntxbPostCode" runat="server" DataType="System.Int32"
    MaxLength="4" TabIndex="4" Width="95%" DecimalDigits="0" ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="getCityByPinCode()">
 </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>

 <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCity" runat="server" Width="95%" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
</body>
```

Web service:

```
public string CityBasedOnPinCode(string pincode)
{
    int pcode = 0;
    int.TryParse(pincode, out pcode);
    List<usp_CityBasedOnPinCodeResult> lstCity = new CityDA().CityBasedOnPincode(pcode);
    return lstCity[0].CityName.ToString();
}
```

I want to fill city textbox on the base of pincode entered.So when User Enters pincode,he/she gets city name automatically.When I put value of pincode predefined it gives me perfect result but when i am entering new value i got error as follows

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected.

Note that if i have value of pincode in textbox  at page load time(edit time) Then i am getting proper value but not getting value after changing value of textbox.
jQuery is included in masterpage. so not included here.

Comment: Have you checked in firebug to see if you get a more specific error message?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using your 'city' variable to reference your textbox when setting the value in the OnSuccess code?

Comment: @patmortech : There is no Use Of Variable city. It was used before.now I am directly giving value to textbox instead of using city

Comment: @ Jack Marchetti : the specific error that fierbug shows is "b[a] is not a function"

Comment: Have you put breakpoints in Firebug in your three functions above to see exactly what part of the process is throwing the error?

Comment: @patmortech : ya but it doesn't goes to function that i written.When value changed It directly throws error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are subscribing to the client-side event offered by the RadNumericTextBox it might be easier to use the event arguments in your code as opposed to using a selector to get a hold of the value. You can see an example of how to get the new value from the OnValueChanged event [right here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-onvaluechanged.html).

Along with this, when I changed the code to the following everything worked fine on my end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCityByPinCode(sender, eventArgs) {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="ntxbPostCode" runat="server" DataType="System.Int32"
    MaxLength="4" TabIndex="4" Width="95%" DecimalDigits="0" ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="getCityByPinCode">
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxCity" runat="server" Width="95%" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

This prevented the event from firing on initial page load (which it was with your code) and also ensure that I managed to get the new value of the RadNumericTextBox with the **get_newValue()** function.

Small note: you should be able to just use the city variable in the OnSuccess function to set its value, as opposed to calling getElementbyID again.

Comment: Specifically, I believe the problem could be his use of () after the function name in the property of the textbox.

Comment: Agreed, that is the most probably culprit as all the other JavaScript checks out. Using the () in the property will have the function be called on page load and if nothing is in the RadNumericTextBox at that time it will of course fail. Might be good to set up some checks for that as well.

Comment: @patmortech you Are Right Sir..
Thanks To You and all who Has showen interest and helped me...